# Allow overlapping polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, overlapping-features, topology, digitizing

When I draw a polygon in QGIS that overlaps an existing polygon from the same layer, QGIS automatically clips the overlapping area from the new polygon.

Is there a setting to preserve the shape that I have draw with the overlapping part?

Comment: Do you have tracing/clipping activated? Do you have checked all you digitizing-settings?

Comment: Ah I see, the problem was that "Allow Overlapping" was not activated in the digitizing settings.

Comment: For what it's worth... Given there's an answer upvoted multiple times, I think this deserves not to be closed. There's potential that this will help future readers with the same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the panel "snapping toolbar"
[image]